# Gmock const method not called instead calling the original method

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have interface which is defined as
in .h file

```
namespace diagnostic{
class class1interface{
virtual int readpowerstate()const =0;
virtual int readparameters() = 0;
}
class class1 : public class1interface{
int readpowerstate()const;
int readparameters();}};
```

in .cc file i have the function

```
int diagnostic::readparameters(){
if(diagnostic::readpowerstate ==1)
    { //Dothis}
else
    {return 0}}
```

i have to execute the else part since by default the if will get called when i run the program. So i tried to use gmock as follows.

```
class Mock_class : public diagnostic::class1interface{
public:
Mock_class(){}
MOCK_METHOD0(readparameters,int());
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(readpowerstate,int());};
```

and the gmock test i wrote as follows
// Test the failure of Read Parameters

```
TEST_F(TestBase, readParam_failure){
Mock_class mock_class;
class1 *class_dummmy = new class1();
EXPECT_CALL(mock_class, readpowerstate()).WillOnce(Return(0));
class_dummy->readparameters;
EXPECT_EQ(0, class_dummy->readparameters());}
```

when i'm executing this program i'm getting the error that
error: Actual function call count doesn't match
`EXPECT_CALL(mock_class, readpowerstate())`...
         Expected: to be called at least once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

what is the solution for this since i'm new to gmock.

Comment: sorry that was a typo mistake. (It is class1::readpowerstate == 1).

Comment: That's not how mock tests work. You don't actually use the mock class in your code. You do create a mock object, but you test the actual original class, without injecting the mocked object into the system. That is, instead of `EXPECT_EQ(0, class_dummy->readparameters());}`, you should be injecting `Mock_class` into the system, and verify other class using this injected objoect.

Comment: Can you please tell the format for my code how to inject the Mock_class into the system since i'm very new to the gmock.

Comment: Is there any class that communicates with `class1interface` ?

Comment: we are calling the class1interface in another class method as 
int class2::readdata(){
std::unique_ptr<diagnostic::class1interface> classint = std::make_unique<diagnostic::class1>(); 
int value = classint -> readparameters();
return value;
} We are following the same method for all the classes getting called in other classes functions.

Comment: Should we change the source code for the test if we want to use setter of a factory method instead of diagnostic::class1?

Comment: @Karthiksrao on a side note, remember to add virtual destructor to the `class1interface` class; deleting derived objects using pointer to the base class (which is probably the case here) is UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module tests are all about testing an isolated module (like an instance of a selected class) in a mocked environment, specifically, how that module communicates with other objects, and how it responds to various results of these calls. To make this possible, one uses *mocks* in place of that other *real* objects. Mock classes allow to both:

- configure expectations regarding, e.g., the amount/sequence of calls and/or the values of arguments of these calls to specific functions, and verify those by registering all interactions;
- program the results of these expected calls that are returned as if a real object performed some action and responded to the object under test.

This makes it possible to test an object as if it were surrounded by real components, without actually having those. E.g., a device manager can be tested on how it responds to device failures, by mocking a class representing a device and programming that mock to return an error code when some status function is invoked by the manager. That is, no real *device class* is used, and also, no real (faulty!) *device* itself is needed to be connected and configured. The mock will **pretend** to be that device, and what's important, this will all be on a software level.

This, however, is possible only if the class itself is designed in a way that allows us to somehow *inject* mocked objects in place of their real counterparts. Most importantly, the objects in the system need to communicate via interfaces and virtual calls. That is, the aforementioned device manager should not be communicating with, e.g., `DeviceA` (a concrete class name), but instead, some `DeviceInterface`, and so both `DeviceA` and a newly created mock `DeviceMock` could implement that interface and be used in that manager. This way the manager will not even know that it is beeing tested and communicates with a mocked object, and not the real device wrapper.

That is, currently, although you create a mock for `class1interface` you don't actually use that mock. Instead, you try to test `class1`. Creating a mock for `class1interface` is useful only if you aim to test some **other** component (like a class) that communicates with `class1` through `class1interface`, not `class1` itself.

So, having a mock for `class1`, you can e.g. test `class2`. But this requires this class design to meet the conditions I mentioned previously: communicating via interfaces and ability to inject a mock class.

So to meet the conditions, you'd have to rewrite the code:

```
int class2::readdata()
{
    std::unique_ptr<diagnostic::class1interface> classint
         = std::make_unique<diagnostic::class1>();
    int value = classint->readparameters();
    return value;
}
```

to (it's just an example of questionable usefulness, you'd have to adjust it to your needs):

```
int class2::readdata(diagnostic::classinterface* classint)
{
    int value = classint->readparameters();
    return value;
}
```

And so you could write a test for `class2`, injecting a mock of `class1`:

```
TEST_F( TestClass2, readParam_failure )
{
    // Mocks configuration
    Mock_class mock_class;
    EXPECT_CALL( mock_class, readparameters() ).WillOnce(Return(0));

    // System under test configuration
    diagnostic::class2 sut;

    // Test itself
    EXPECT_EQ( 0, sut.readdata(&mock_class) );
}
```

This way you check that the call to `class2::readdata` is properly fowarded to `class1interface::readparameters`, and its result is returned.